# How to Create a Time Table like layout

Tags: android

I would like to create a time table like layout which has a dynamically adjustable lengths as shown in the picture [image]
Please provide some pointers on how to implement this.

Thanks & Regards,
Sen

Comment: This looks like the brick architecture rather than a time-table one.
are you sure you want to do this one or the time table one that can be something like the Excel sheet?

Comment: I think both will be fine for me. If you can provide some help on it, it will be really grateful.

Comment: I surely will.. currently im held by a more serious issue. my emulator can't access the web and I completely don't know why! :-(
Many attempts and efforts are failing. i need to solve that first. can u help in it?

Comment: Are you using Android 2.1 emulator??

Comment: If yes, It will not connect to the Internet if you are inside a proxy environment. Else it should work.

Comment: I was primarily using 2.2, but i tried it with 1.5, 1.6, 2.1 and 2.2 but nothing worked. :-(